# Which of a misaligned store and misaligned load is more expensive?

Tags: performance, assembly, alignment

Suppose I'm copying data between two arrays that are 1024000+1 bytes apart. Since the offset is not a multiple of word size, I'll need to do some misaligned accesses - either loads or stores (for the moment, let's forget that it's possible to avoid misaligned accesses entirely with some ORing and bit shifting). Which of misaligned loads or misaligned stores will be more expensive?

This is a hypothetical situation, so I can't just benchmark it :-) I'm more interested in what factors will lead to performance difference, if any. A pointer to some further reading would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A misaligned write will need to read two destination words, merge in the new data, and write two words. This would be combined with an aligned read. So, 3R + 2W.

A misaligned read will need to read two source words, and merge the data (shift and bitor). This would be combined with an aligned write. So, 2R + 1W.

So, the misaligned read is a clear winner.

Of course, as you say there are more efficient ways to do this that avoid any mis-aligned operations except at the ends of the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that depends greatly on the CPU you are using. On newer Intel CPUs there is no penalty for loading and storing unaligned words (at least none that you can notice). Only if you load and store 16byte or 32byte  unaligned chunks you may see small performance degradation.

Comment: *"On newer Intel CPUs there is no penalty for loading and storing unaligned words"* - Are you sure about that? A number of micro-code instructions will be dispatched to fixup the load and store after the trap. And on older ARMs you will get a `SIGBUS` rather than *enjoy* a performance penalty (been there, done that...).

Comment: I am sure. As long as the data is in L1 cache, and the operation does not cross a cache line boundary it will execute in 1 cycle. Only a split operation requires two memory accesses.
(This is for the latest Intel processors - Westmere and later, not ARM)

Answer (score 1):

How much data?  are we talking about two things unaligned at the ends of a large block of data (in the noise) or one item (word, etc) that is unaligned (100% of the data)?

Are you using a memcpy() to move this data, etc?

> I'm more interested in what factors will lead to performance
>   difference, if any.

Memories, modules, chips, on die blocks, etc are usually organized with a fixed access size, at least somewhere along the way there is a fixed access size.  Lets just say 64 bits wide, not an uncommon size these days.  So at that layer wherever it is you can only write or read in aligned 64 bit units.

If you think about a write vs read, with a read you send out an address and that has to go to the memory and data come back, a full round trip has to happen.  With a write everything you need to know to perform the write goes on the outbound path, so it is not uncommon to have a fire and forget type deal where the memory controller takes the address and data and tells the processor the write has finished even though the information has not net reached the memory.  It does take time but not as long as a read (not talking about flash/proms just ram here) since a read requires both paths.  So for aligned full width stuff a write CAN BE faster, some systems may wait for the data to make it all the way to the memory and then return a completion which is perhaps about the same amount of time as the read.  It depends on your system though, the memory technology can make one or the other faster or slower right at the memory itself.  Now the first write after nothing has been happening can do this fire and forget thing, but the second or third or fourth or 16th in a row eventually fills up a buffer somewhere along the path and the processor has to wait for the oldest one to make it all the way to the memory before the most recent one has a place in the queue.  So for bursty stuff writes may be faster than reads but for large movements of data they approach each other.

Now alignment.  The whole memory width will be read on a read, in this case lets say 64 bits, if you were only really interested in 8 of those bits, then somewhere between the memory and the processor the other 24 bits are discarded, where depends on the system.  Writes that are not a whole, aligned, size of the memory mean that you have to read the width of the memory, lets say 64 bits, modify the new bits, say 8 bits, then write the whole 64 bits back.  A read-modify-write.  A read only needs a read a write needs a read-modify-write, the farther away from the memory requiring the read modify write the longer it takes the slower it is, no matter what the read-modify-write cant be any faster than the read alone so the read will be faster, the trimming of bits off the read generally wont take any time so reading a byte compared to reading 16 bits or 32 or 64 bits from the same location so long as the busses and destination are that width all the way, take the same time from the same location, in general, or should.

Unaligned simply multiplies the problem.  Say worst case if you want to read 16 bits such that 8 bits are in one 64 bit location and the other 8 in the next 64 bit location, you need to read 128 bits to satisfy that 16 bit read.  How that exactly happens and how much of a penalty is dependent on your system.  some busses set up the transfer X number of clocks but the data is one clock per bus width after that so a 128 bit read might be only one clock longer (than the dozens to hundreds) of clocks it takes to read 64, or worst case it could take twice as long in order to get the 128 bits needed for this 16 bit read.  A write, is a read-modify-write so take the read time, then modify the two 64 bit items, then write them back, same deal could be X+1 clocks in each direction or could be as bad as 2X number of clocks in each direction.

Caches help and hurt.  A nice thing about using caches is that you can smooth out the transfers to the slow memory, you can let the cache worry about making sure all memory accesses are aligned and all writes are whole 64 bit writes, etc.  How that happens though is the cache will perform same or larger sized reads.  So reading 8 bits may result in one or many 64 bit reads of the slow memory, for the first byte, if you perform a second read right after that of the next byte location and if that location is in the same cache line then it doesnt go out to slow memory, it reads from the cache, much faster. and so on until you cross over into another cache boundary or other reads cause that cache line to be evicted.  If the location being written is in cache then the read-modify-write happens in the cache, if not in cache then it depends on the system, a write doesnt necessarily mean the read modify write causes a cache line fill, it could happen on the back side as of the cache were not there.  Now if you modified one byte in the cache line, now that line has to be written back it simply cannot be discarded so you have a one to few widths of the memory to write back as a result.  your modification was fast but eventually the write happens to the slow memory and that affects the overall performance.

You could have situations where you do a (byte) read, the cache line if bigger than the external memory width can make that read slower than if the cache wasnt there, but then you do a byte write to some item in that cache line and that is fast since it is in the cache. So you might have experiments that happen to show writes are faster.

A painful case would be reading say 16 bits unaligned such that not only do they cross over a 64 bit memory width boundary but the cross over a cache line boundary, such that two cache lines have to be read, instead of reading 128 bits that might mean 256 or 512 or 1024 bits have to be read just to get your 16.

The memory sticks on your computer for example are actually multiple memories, say maybe 8 8 bit wide to make a 64 bit overall width or 16 4 bit wide to make an overall 64 bit width, etc.  That doesnt mean you can isolate writes on one lane, but maybe, I dont know those modules very well but there are systems where you can/could do this, but those systems I would consider to be 8 or 4 bit wide as far as the smallest addressable size not 64 bit as far as this discussion goes.  ECC makes things worse though.  First you need an extra memory chip or more, basically more width 72 bits to support 64 for example.  You must do full writes with ECC as the whole 72 bits lets say has to be self checking so you cant do fractions.  if there is a correctable (single bit) error the read suffers no real penalty it gets the corrected 64 bits (somewhere in the path where this checking happens).  Ideally you want a system to write back that corrected value but that is not how all systems work so a read could turn into a read modify write, aligned or not.  The primary penalty is if you were able to do fractional writes you cant now with ECC has to be whole width writes.

Now to my question, lets say you use memcpy to move this data, many C libraries are tuned to do aligned transfers, at least where possible, if the source and destination are unaligned in a different way that can be bad, you might want to manage part of the copy yourself.  say they are unaligned in the same way, the memcpy will try to copy the unaligned bytes first until it gets to an aligned boundary, then it shifts into high gear, copying aligned blocks until it gets near the end, it downshifts and copies the last few bytes if any, in an unaligned fashion.  so if this memory copy you are talking about is thousands of bytes and the only unaligned stuff is near the ends then yes it will cost you some extra reads as much as two extra cache line fills, but that may be in the noise.  Even on smaller sizes even if aligned on say 32 bit boundaries if you are not moving whole cache lines or whole memory widths there may still be an extra cache line involved, aligned or not you might only suffer an extra cache lines worth of reading and later writing...

The pure traditional, non-cached memory view of this, all other things held constant is as Doug wrote.  Unaligned reads across one of these boundaries, like the 16 bits across two 64 bit words, costs you an extra read 2R vs 1R.  A similar write costs you 2R+2W vs 1W, much more expensive.  Caches and other things just complicate the problem greatly making the answer "it depends"...You need to know your system pretty well and what other stuff is going on around it, if any.  Caches help and hurt, with any cache a test can be crafted to show the cache makes things slower and with the same system a test can be written to show the cache makes things faster.

Further reading would be go look at the databooks/sheets technical reference manuals or whatever the vendor calls their docs for various things.  for ARM get the AXI/AMBA documentation on their busses, get the cache documentation for their cache (PL310 for example).  Information on ddr memory the individual chips used in the modules you plug into your computer are all out there, lots of timing diagrams, etc. (note just because you think you are buying gigahertz memory, you are not, dram has not gotten faster in like 10 years or more, it is pretty slow around 133Mhz, it is just that the bus is faster and can queue more transfers, it still takes hundreds to thousands of processor cycles for a ddr memory cycle, read one byte that misses all the caches and you processor waits an eternity).  so memory interfaces on the processors and docs on various memories, etc may help, along with text books on caches in general, etc.